# Timer app in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

I created an app which counts days, hours, minutes and seconds until some event.

I learned a lot while creating it and as always I would love some feedback from you guys to improve my code by learning from mistakes and maybe implement a better solution. In particular, I am not very proud of the way my `startTimer()` works.

```js
'use strict';
// #####################################################################
// start - event name and calculating difference between the event and today

const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start-btn');
const resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset-btn');
const eventName = document.querySelector('#event-name');
const eventDate = document.querySelector('#event-date');
const eventTime = document.querySelector('#event-time');
const untilParagraph = document.querySelector('.until');

let isStartClicked = false;

startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const today = new Date();
  let eventDay = new Date(eventDate.value);

  if (isValid('time')) {
    const splitedTime = eventTime.value.split(':');
    eventDay.setHours(splitedTime[0]);
    eventDay.setMinutes(splitedTime[1]);
  }

  //date in the past
  if (eventDay.getTime() < today.getTime()) {
    const message = document.querySelector('.message');
    message.classList.remove('hidden');

    const messageClose = document.querySelector('.message__close');
    messageClose.addEventListener('click', () => {
      message.classList.add('hidden');
    });

    return;
  }

  if (isValid('name') && isValid() && !isStartClicked) {
    untilParagraph.innerHTML = `<span class='until--until'>until</span> ${eventName.value}`;

    let difference = eventDay - today; //in ms

    const daysLeft = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    difference -= daysLeft * 1000 * 3600 * 24;

    let hoursLeft, minutesLeft, secondsLeft;

    hoursLeft = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 3600));
    difference -= hoursLeft * 1000 * 3600;

    minutesLeft = Math.floor(difference / (1000 * 60));
    difference -= minutesLeft * 1000 * 60;

    secondsLeft = Math.floor(difference / 1000);
    difference -= secondsLeft * 1000;

    startTimer({ daysLeft, hoursLeft, minutesLeft, secondsLeft });

    isStartClicked = true;
  }
});

// #####################################################################
// reset

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  stopTimer();
  insertTime({ daysLeft: 0, hoursLeft: 0, minutesLeft: 0, secondsLeft: 0 });
  isStartClicked = false;
});

// #####################################################################
// Validation

const isValid = (type) => {
  if (type === 'name') {
    if (eventName.value) return true;
    return false;
  } else if (type === 'time') {
    const timePattern = /^([0-1][0-9]|[2][0-3]):([0-5][0-9])$/;
    if (!timePattern.test(eventTime.value)) return false;
    else return true;
  } else {
    // date
    const datePattern = /^(((0[13-9]|1[012])[-/]?(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|30)|(0[13578]|1[02])[-/]?31|02[-/]?(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))[-/]?[0-9]{4}|02[-/]?29[-/]?([0-9]{2}(([2468][048]|[02468][48])|[13579][26])|([13579][26]|[02468][048]|0[0-9]|1[0-6])00))$/;
    if (!datePattern.test(eventDate.value)) return false;
    else return true;
  }
};

eventName.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if (!isValid('name'))
    document.querySelector('#name-invalid').classList.remove('hidden');
  else document.querySelector('#name-invalid').classList.add('hidden');
});

eventDate.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if (!isValid('date'))
    document.querySelector('#date-invalid').classList.remove('hidden');
  else document.querySelector('#date-invalid').classList.add('hidden');
});

eventTime.addEventListener('blur', () => {
  if (!isValid('time'))
    document.querySelector('#time-invalid').classList.remove('hidden');
  else document.querySelector('#time-invalid').classList.add('hidden');
});

// #####################################################################
// Timer
let interval;

const startTimer = (time) => {
  interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (
      time.daysLeft != 0 ||
      time.hoursLeft != 0 ||
      time.minutesLeft != 0 ||
      time.secondsLeft != 0
    ) {
      if (time.secondsLeft > 0) {
        time.secondsLeft -= 1;
      } else {
        time.secondsLeft = 59;
        if (time.minutesLeft > 0) time.minutesLeft -= 1;
        else {
          time.minutesLeft = 59;
          if (time.hoursLeft > 0) time.hoursLeft -= 1;
          else {
            time.hoursLeft = 23;
            if (time.daysLeft > 0) time.daysLeft -= 1;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    insertTime(time);
  }, 1000);
};

const stopTimer = () => {
  clearInterval(interval);
};

const insertTime = (time) => {
  document.querySelector('.days').textContent =
    time.daysLeft < 10 ? `0${time.daysLeft}` : time.daysLeft;
  document.querySelector('.hours').textContent =
    time.hoursLeft < 10 ? `0${time.hoursLeft}` : time.hoursLeft;
  document.querySelector('.minutes').textContent =
    time.minutesLeft < 10 ? `0${time.minutesLeft}` : time.minutesLeft;
  document.querySelector('.seconds').textContent =
    time.secondsLeft < 10 ? `0${time.secondsLeft}` : time.secondsLeft;
};

// TODO:
// ? Improve algorythmic notation of timer
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Ubuntu:wght@300;400;500;700&display=swap");
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #111010;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

main .menu {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5rem 15rem;
  border: 2px solid #fffbfc;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

main .menu div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
  color: #fffbfc;
  position: relative;
}

main .menu div:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

main .menu div label {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

main .menu div label span {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  color: #c2c2c2;
  font-weight: 300;
}

main .menu div input {
  padding: 1rem 0.7rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: #292727;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fffbfc;
}

main .menu div input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #c2c2c2;
}

main .menu div input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c2c2c2;
}

main .menu div input::-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #c2c2c2;
}

main .menu div input::placeholder {
  color: #c2c2c2;
}

main .menu div .valid-info {
  color: #e94949;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
}

main .menu .btn {
  height: 45px;
  width: 80px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
  border: 2px solid #fffbfc;
  color: #fffbfc;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.8rem 1.3rem;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main .menu .btn:hover {
  background-color: #fffbfc;
  color: black;
}

main .menu .btn--margin-small {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

main .menu .btn--margin-big {
  margin-left: 3rem;
}

main .event {
  padding: 10rem 15rem;
}

main .event .timer-box {
  color: white;
  font-size: 8rem;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  font-weight: 500;
}

main .event .timer-box p {
  font-size: 5rem;
}

main .event .timer-box .days,
main .event .timer-box .hours,
main .event .timer-box .minutes,
main .event .timer-box .seconds {
  position: relative;
}

main .event .timer-box .days::before,
main .event .timer-box .hours::before,
main .event .timer-box .minutes::before,
main .event .timer-box .seconds::before {
  font-size: 1rem;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #c2c2c2;
  font-weight: 300;
}

main .event .timer-box .days::before {
  content: 'days';
}

main .event .timer-box .hours::before {
  content: 'hours';
}

main .event .timer-box .minutes::before {
  content: 'minutes';
}

main .event .timer-box .seconds::before {
  content: 'seconds';
}

main .event .until {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #c2c2c2;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  text-align: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: end;
      align-self: flex-end;
}

main .event .until--until {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  color: #aaaaaa;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.message {
  color: black;
  font-weight: 500;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10rem;
  left: 50%;
  padding: 2rem 4rem;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.message__close {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: scale 0.3s;
  transition: scale 0.3s;
}

.message__close:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
          transform: scale(1.5);
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css">
    <title>Countdown</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <form action="#" class="menu">
            <div>        
                <label for="event-name">Event name</label>
                <input type="text" id='event-name' placeholder="New Year Party" required>
                <p class='valid-info hidden' id="name-invalid">Invalid name</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="event-date">Date</label>
                <input type="text" id='event-date' placeholder="12/31/2020" required>
                <p class='valid-info hidden' id="date-invalid">Invalid date</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="event-time">Time <span>(optional)</span></label>
                <input type="text" id='event-time' placeholder="20:00">
                <p class='valid-info hidden' id="time-invalid">Invalid time</p>
            </div>
            <button class='btn btn--margin-big start-btn'>Start</button>
            <a href="#" class='btn btn--margin-small reset-btn'>Reset</a>
        </form>

        <div class="event">
            <div class="timer-box">
                <div class="days">00</div>
                <p>:</p>
                <div class="hours">00</div>
                <p>:</p>
                <div class="minutes">00</div>
                <p>:</p>
                <div class="seconds">00</div>
            </div>
            <div class="until"> <span class='until--until'>until</span> New Year Party</div>
        </div>
        <p class="message hidden">Your event has already happend
            <a href="#" class="message__close">x</a>
        </p>
    </main>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not look bad :)

Thing I'd improve:

- Avoid styling using the HTML tags. Use classes instead
- color: #c2c2c2; is repeated a lot. Use one CSS selector that applies this style to multiple elements instead of repeating it
- : in your timer should not be a paragraph. I'd pick a span instead
- I'd add a test or at least a comment for the regExp. Or maybe a variable with a descriptive name ?
- ```
  if (
           time.daysLeft != 0 ||
           time.hoursLeft != 0 ||
           time.minutesLeft != 0 ||
           time.secondsLeft != 0
  ```

  .... should be replaced by a JS `.some()` method that would repurn true if one of the elements meets the condition
- Add curly braces on if/else statements